# Cannot convert ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>

Tags: java, object, arraylist, boxing

I have a function `foo` which accept a parameter `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`. When I tried to call the function by passing a variable with type of `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, the compiler shows error message that says :

```
incompatible types: 
java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>> 
cannot be converted into  
java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>>
```

What should I change/do in order to make the function accept parameter(s) with 2D `ArrayList` with any type? Thanks in advance.

Sample code

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> foo (ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> parameter)
{
    //do something
}
```

Calling the function

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> parameter;
//do something with the parameter
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> product = foo(parameter);//red line under parameter indicate it has error
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: You could have your method accept `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>` if that suits your purpose. Without casting, you wouldn't be able to put anything into it, but you'd be able to get objects out of it.

Comment: I have tried `ArrayList<?>`, but it does not work. And also it occur a problem when I tried to initiate it `new ArrayList<?>`

Comment: you cannot instantiate `<?>` generic type; you can only use it to refer to existing objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

**1.Use generic (and btw should use List instead of ArrayList)**

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> foo(List<List<T>> parameter) {
    //do something
}

public void test() {
    List<List<Integer>> parameter;
    //do something with the parameter
    List<List<Integer>> product = foo(parameter);
}
```

**2.Use nested wildcards:**

```
public static List<? extends List<? extends Object>> foo(List<? extends List<? extends Object>> parameter) {
    //do something
}

public void test() {
    List<List<Integer>> parameter = new ArrayList<>();
    //do something with the parameter
    foo(parameter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make it generic:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> foo (ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> parameter) {
  //do something

  // you probably want to create a new 2D ArrayList somewhere around here
  ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> ret = new ArrayList<>();

  //do more somethings
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Btw, may I know what's the difference between `T`, `?` and `Object` in java ?

Comment: Sure thing! https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-using-T-and-a-wildcard-in-Java-Generics

Comment: Thanks for the link, it do help.